# Magento 2 upgrade - Setup:upgrade stuck at Magento_Customer

Tags: magento2, magento-upgrade, setup-upgrade, magento2.4.3.p1, data-install

I am trying to upgrade Magento 2.2.1 to Magento 2.4.3-p1 using composer and successfully new version upgrade but when run upgrade command but process stuck not progress process of from Data install/update Magento_Customer. See the below image.

Also, not showing any error in error log and apache2 error log, I have try all possibility but it's last stuck in Magento_Customer

`php bin/magento setup:di:compile`  Successfully done not any error but setup:upgrade stuck

Why not showing error ?

[image]

Comment: How many customer do you have?

Comment: 535 only customer @SohelRana

Comment: Now issues fixed I have set the max_execution_time 18000, max_input_time 18000, max_input_vars 50000, memory_limit 4096M and apache restart in my case not any error come show in exception and system log.

Comment: The above comment solves my issue thank @BhaveshGodhani

Comment: Welcome @Kashif

Answer (score 0):

> You can check by run below command:

```
strace -s 99 bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

More about [strace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strace#:%7E:text=strace%20is%20a%20diagnostic%2C%20debugging,and%20changes%20of%20process%20state.)

> **Also, check your MySQL has not run any related process, you found then kill it. (Not KILL ALL, only related Processes need to kill)**

```
SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST

kill ProcessID
```

> **In My case customer_visitor table cause an error and stops the command. After debugging more in DB, there are many entries, so he takes more time to run and stop the upgrade command execution.**

> **I remove all entries from **customer_visitor** table and then It's working.**

```
TRUNCATE TABLE customer_visitor;
```